# How to alloc a subclass of Object (not a subclass of NSObject)

Tags: objective-c

If I want to use the core objc beyond any cocoa or gnustep,
then the root class is `Object`. This `Object` apparently lacks `+alloc` method. Then how can an instance of its subclass be allocated?

The `Object.h` of gcc says:

> /* The Object class is a very minimal root class included with the
>    runtime.  It is used as superclass for the two classes included
>    with the runtime, Protocol and NXConstantString.
>
> Because Objective-C allows multiple root classes, you can define
>    your own root class, different from Object.
>
> In particular, a Foundation library (such as GNUstep Base) is
>    expected to provide its own root class (typically called NSObject),
>    fully integrated with the library's own high-level features.  It is
>    expected that you should always use and interact with NSObject, and
>    mostly ignore Object.  */

So is `NSObject` a subclass of `Object`? Or is it a completely independent class? Then how `+alloc` is defined? I am very confused.